# formatting python string that contains ${}

Tags: python, string, format

I need to print out a string that contains ${} with format() method

For example, I'd like to print out

`"hello ${a} hello"`

using this python code

```
print "{string1} ${a} {string1}".format(string1="hello")
```

However, I get  KeyError'a', as format() expects an input string for {a}.
How can I teach format() to ignore ${a}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to double the { and } to {{ to }}:

```
print "{string1} ${{a}} {string1}".format(string1="hello")
```

Comment: This works well when you want to print an equal number of open and close curly braces, but python chokes on it if you only want to print an a single open brace.  '{{{}}' does not work.  In this case I just added the single curly brace as an additional parameter to my .format() and injected into the string that way.